# SQL Server Parent/Child Ordering (Possible Recursion?)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to generate a query that lists a parent node with each of it's children nodes and that children's nodes (etc etc) below each other. Exactly the same way that you would structure a comment with a reply and a reply to that.

For example, given this data:

```
ID    ParentID
--------------
1    0
2    0
3    2
4    2
5    0
6    1
7    2
8    7
```

I would like to get a query structured like this:

```
ID    ParentID
--------------
1    0
6    1
2    0
3    2
4    2
7    2
8    7
5    0
```

I know I need a Recursive CTE I believe, but how?

Thanks

Comment: Does it require multiple levels of parenting: is (9, 8) a possibility?

Comment: @TI Thank you very much - awarded to you in the linked to post.

Comment: Tip: It is common to use a `ParentID` of NULL to indicate a top level node. It avoids special handling for magic numbers or the confusion of setting a node to be its own parent to indicate a root.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you'd like to do a DFS (Depth First Search) on the tree structure stored in a table.

```
                0
             /  |  \
            /   |   \
           /    |    \
          /     |     \
         1      2      5
         |    / | \
         6   3  4  7
                   |
                   8
```

The logic of your code would be:

```
DFS(Node p){
    children = GetChildren(p)
    foreach (c in children) {
        Print("ID: " + c + " Parent ID: " + p)
        DFS(c)
    }
}
```

Now SQL Server.
Selecting the nodes who are directly the children of a given node is easy:

```
SELECT [ID] FROM [Table] WHERE [ParentID] = @parentID
```

Create a temp table to store the results:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp(ID int, ParentID int);
```

Then either recursively SELECT INTO the results table or do it in a while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this ...

```
;WITH
  cte (EmpID, ParentID, EmpLevel)
  AS
  (
    SELECT ID, ParentID, 1
    FROM Table
    WHERE ParentID = 0

    UNION ALL

    SELECT t.ID, t.ParentID,c.EmpLevel + 1
    FROM Table t
      INNER JOIN cte c
        ON t.ParentID = c.EmpID
  )
SELECT
  EmpID,EmpLevel
FROM cte
ORDER BY EmpID,EmpLevel
```